# Set up openid-connect infrastructure

Tags: authentication, authorization, backend, openid-connect, keycloak

I am pretty new to Authorization/Authentication with openid connect. I guess I lack some basic understanding on how to set up a proper backend infrastructure.

There's a keycloak server running through which I want to authorize/authenticate my customers.
The user logs in by his company credentials and then should be authorized/authenticated against our backend service, which provides a REST-API.

So our part is to implement the backend service and use openid connect as authorization/authentication.
Could you tell me what components/software needs to be implemented on our side?

Answer (score 0):

Often the Authorization Server is an external cloud system that your UIs and APIs just point to, with URLs equivalent to this:

- https://api.mycompany.com/myapi
- https://web.mycompany.app/myapp
- https://login.mycompany.com

Not sure if this quite matches your setup but typically you provide some or all of these domains:

- API
- Web Hosting
- Authorization Server (Keycloak)

My personal preference is to use [Local Developer PC Domains](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/15/developer-domain-setup/) to match the above. If it helps you might just be able to repoint my [Open Id Connect
Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1) to your infra once configured, in order to verify that it works.